# Declare global Razor Page variables in ASP.NET MVC [NOT Static]

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a ConfigurationService class that is injected in "_ViewImports":

```
@inject IConfigurationService ConfigurationService
```

And I access it in each View Page like below:

```
@{
    // Configurations
    var configuration = await ConfigurationService.GetGeneralConfiguration();
    var currencySymbol = configuration.Currency.Symbol;
}
```

This works, but I have to copy and paste the code in each page. I've tried to write the code in `_Layout.cshtml` but it doesn't work. Static vars also don't work because the values are not static - for each request I get the current user configuration and inject into the page. And, for all pages that require the `currencySymbol` variable value I need to paste code, and I don't want to have to do this.

My question is: How can I declare variables in, for example, `_Layout.cshtml`, or `_ViewStart.cshtml` or some other view that can be accessed by all razor view pages, like inherits. These variables must contain ConfigurationService values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of creating variables, you're better off injecting a service that will generate the values you need as required. For example:

```
public interface ILocalisationService
{
    string CurrencySymbol { get; }
}

public class LocalisationService : ILocalisationService
{
    private IConfigurationService _configurationService;
    private string _currencySymbol;

    public LocalisationService(IConfigurationService configurationService)
    {
        _configurationService = configurationService;
    }

    public string CurrencySymbol => string.IsNullOrEmpty(_currencySymbol)
        ? _currencySymbol = _configurationService.GetValue("£")
        : _currencySymbol;
}
```

Now inject the new service:

```
@inject ILocalisationService LocalisationService
```

And use it in your view:

```
The currency symbol is @LocalisationService.CurrencySymbol
```

The benefit of this is that when your view doesn't use one of the values, it doesn't need to get calculated, which is especially relevant if it takes a long time.

Comment: You missing to add the new service to **ConfigureServices** on **Startup** like this: `services.AddSingleton<ILocalizationService, LocalizationService>();`

Comment: @Max Well yes, but since OP is already doing DI, they will know how to do that.

Comment: Of course, but a new user might not know it and would not be able to get your code working